# Is it possible to have a shared runtime without a Yeoman generated project?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to add a shared runtime to my MS Word Add-in.

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) it says "These steps assume you have generated your project using the Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins.".

I have not generated my project with the Yeoman generator.

Is it possible to have a shared runtime without a Yeoman generated project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) article provides all the necessary steps for setting up the shared runtime in the manifest file. Due to the fact that webpack is not used in VS projects you don't need to do [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime#configure-the-webpackconfigjs-file) in your solution.

Don't forget about [Shared runtime requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/shared-runtime-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview).